# Send an email from App using your GMail account as a SMTP server

Tags: email, ssl, smtp, plesk

"Allow less secure apps" is "ON" in my GMail Account, but still I am unable to send an email using "smtp.gmail.com" as SMTP Server from external App like Web hosting server, Plesk

Comment: I can send an email from some of the Desktop app, but not succeed to send an email from the website hosted on Plesk server

Comment: The solution for this is 1. First do login to your gmail account which you have used(configured) for sending an email in your external app. 2. Then open a new tab in browser & pest below url https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha & click on "continue" button.

Answer (score 0):

After doing lot of search on internet, finally I follow these links & found the solution.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4KZPLJuja6Y

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=1-636162579008089451-153786151&rd=2#cantsignin

Answer (score 0):

Continue from above post.......

The Problem is that I could able to send email from some of my desktop App, but not succeed to send an email from Plesk server (Web hosting server). The solution for this is

1. First do login to your gmail account which you have used(configured) for sending an email in your external app.
2. Then open a new tab in browser & pest below url https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
   & click on "continue" button.

This will now allow to send an email from app hosted on Plesk server.